# Is it possible to dynamically change some html content on this accordion jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, accordion, title, innerhtml

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-accordion/

http://jquery.bassistance.de/accordion/demo/

Kind of like the third example, except the "icon" should not be an image, but a text character.
I would like to have this title : "+ guitar" changing to "- guitar" when I select this option.
My html should be like this :

```
<a><span>+<span> guitar</a>
```

to

```
<a><span>-<span> guitar</a>
```

Any idea about how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the images from the css and use the :before selector with the content element.

Change

```
#navigation a.head {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background:#5263AB url(collapsed.gif) no-repeat scroll 3px 4px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-indent:14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a.selected {
    background-image: url(expanded.gif);
}
```

to

```
#navigation a.head {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background:#5263AB;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-indent:14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a.head:before {
    content: '+';
}

#navigation a.selected:before {
    content: '-';
}
```

Comment: I used this solution. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I just had a quick look at the example linked, the following may not be true for the jquery accordion which is a component based on the linked javascript library.

The image you are seeing is set via CSS and in fact the background image for this element:

```
 #navigation a.head (all closed "tabs")
```

and

```
 #navigation a.selected (the one currently expanded).
```

So you basically have two options:

- create images that ressemble '-' and '+', problably the easiest hack
- play with jQuery's .html for those selectors and by that changing the preprended string '-' with '+' and vice versa

Comment: I could change the innerhtml of the wanted <a> each time the accordion function is started... But I don't find how to do that. :(